# System.AccessViolationException when calling Active Directory FindAll()

Tags: active-directory, access-violation, directoryservices, findall

I have a simple snippet of code in C# .Net 4 that randomly gives a access violation when calling .FindAll() on DirectorySearcher in System.DirectoryServices

All that the method does is find out if a user is loaded in Active Directory and return the 
Directory Entry.

I've searched the net and can find multiple mentions of the exception all in SharePoint blogs and forums, but none from a normal C# .net 4 service.

My question is would this same accessviolation occur on my service, thus would I need the same hotfix to solve my issue?

The hotfix:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/4634f4f4-7857-4de3-9bc5-fcbb946bd8df

The code:

```
            deSearch.Filter = String.Format("(&(SAMAccountName={0}))", userName);

            using (SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll())
            {
                if (results.Count > 0)
                {
                    de = results[0].GetDirectoryEntry();
                    return de;
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
```

The Exception:

System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntADsOpen.GetObject(String className, String relativeName)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.Find(String name, String schemaClassName)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.Find(String name)